# UITextView memory leak

Tags: iphone

Can somebody can please verify that they can also reproduce that memory leak.

Create a new "Utility Application". Open the FlipsideView.xib and add a UITextview. Using the inspector, uncheck "Editable" and check "Detects Phone Number" and "Detects Links".

Run the app using the Leak instrument on an iPhone. Flip between the MainView and the FlipsideView a few times and observe the leak.

Thanks

I'm using 3.1.2

Comment: It's present using Debug configuration but not when using Release configuration. Should the Release configuration always be used when using the instrument?

Comment: No leaks. Tried few times. No leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Your leak seems to be somewhere else, i tried what you say and no leaks show up when im using 3.1.2 .
However, i must add i did not connect the uitextview with IBOutlet as you did not mention it. If you are using

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *....

it may cause a leak if you do not release your IBOutlet in  dealloc.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I didn't connect it. I didn't add any code at all. I just did what I described.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run Leaks against a real device, and not the simulator.  I've found in the past that leaks were reported running my app against the simulator, but when I ran against a real device, those reported leaks went away.

Comment: Actually, the leak is only present when I run it on my device.